# Hitting F5 after submit the page in asp.net?

Tags: .net

I have web page with submit button, after submit the page when the user press F5 to refresh the page it'll do the thing which was done by last request.

I have omit this by redirecting again the same page in submit_click function in C# Code behind itself.

but i feel it'll create some performance problem when number of user's hit is increase.

I have tried Server.Transfer also. but both of them is not right solution to protect against the problem.

Is there any solution to over come from this problem?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[Post/Redirect/Get Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)** to minimize the issue of form resubmission.

However this is not fully secure.There is still a chance that the user might resubmit the form by clicking the back button and again reloading.The browser confirms before resubmission though.

**[Useful aricle.](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Post-Redirect-Get.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a value to the button that is used to submit the form, for instance value="isClicked".

Before handling the the request you can check if that button has a value.

```
if (Request.Form["answer-thread"] != null && String.Equals(Request.Form["answer-thread"], "isClicked"))

{
 var answerText = Request.Form["answer-text"].ToString();
.... do your form logic. 
}
```

when refreshing the page the button will be empty. Hope this works for u

Best Regards 
Henrik